# strtotime() converts a non existing date to another date

Tags: php, function, date, strtotime

I am building a timestamp from the date, month and year values entered by users.

Suppose that the user inputs some wrong values and the date is "31-02-2012" which does not exist, then I have to get a false return. But here its converting it to another date nearby. Precisely to: "02-03-2012"..

I dont want this to happen..

```
$str = "31-02-2012";
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($str)); // Outputs 02-03-2012
```

Can anyone help? I dont want a timestamp to be returned if the date is not original.

Comment: I think that's actually the correct and documented behaviour that you're describing. Can you write what your actual problem is? Do you need to validate a date-string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `strtotime()` has troubles with `-` since they are used to denote phrase like `-1 week`, etc...

Try

```
$str = '31-02-2012';
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $str)));
```

**However** `31-02-2012` is not a valid English format, it should be `02-31-2012`.

---

If you have *PHP >= 5.3*, you can use [`createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$str = '31-02-2012';
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $str);
echo $d->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: I think you'll find that the English (as in England, and most other places for that matter) format _is_ dd mm yy. That would be the cyan bit here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country. It's only the US that insists on the ridiculous format :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Well, [`strtotime`](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) docs claim it would _"[p]arse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp"_. That's the English format I was referring to. :)

Comment: awsome bro.. replacing the "-" with the "/" got me workin..  however the createFromFormat is not working in my end and my php version is 5.3.5.. does it require a still higher version?

Comment: @mithunsatheesh Nope, that's a high enough version. `DateTime` is part of the PHP core since PHP 5.2, and the function `createFromFormat` since 5.3, so it should be available. If you share the error you were getting or the behavior we might help as to why it didn't work.

Comment: @Shef PHP 5.3.2 here.  DateTime::createFromFormat() gives me current timestamp when checking 02/31/2012.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething If you use a slash as a separator, you would do `$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $str);`

Comment: @Shef It's not that it won't parse the date, it's that it accepts Feb 31 as a valid day & ends up generating March 2.  I guess this is just the sort of behavior that I should expect from PHP and not act surprised.

Answer (score 4):

You might look into [`checkdate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check if the date is possible before using strtotime. Strtotime will convert it to unix date meaning it will use seconds since... This means it will always be a date.

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround this behavior

```
<?php
$str = "31-02-2012";
$unix = strtotime($str); 
echo date('d-m-Y', $unix);
if (date('d-m-Y', $unix) != $str){
   echo "wrong";
}
else{
   echo date("d-m-Y", $unx);
}
```

or just use [`checkdate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use the checkdate function.

```
$str = "31-02-2012";
$years = explode("-", $str);
$valid_date = checkdate($years[1], $years[0], $years[2]);
```

[Checkdate Function - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) & [Explode Function - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Combine date_parse and checkdate to check if it's a valid time.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

function is_valid_date($str) {
    $date = date_parse($str);
    return checkdate($date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year']);
}

print is_valid_date('31-02-2012') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
print "\n";
print is_valid_date('28-02-2012') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
print "\n";
```

Even though that date format is acceptable according to PHP [date formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), it may still cause issues for date parsers because it's easy to confuse the month and day. For example, `02-03-2012`, it's hard to tell if 02 is the month or the day. It's better to use the other more specific date parser examples here to first parse the date then check it with checkdate.