# strtotime date validation passes on invalid date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am in the middle of setting up a  basic CMS that allows the client to add articles to their mobile app. The CMS is coded in PHP and will use JSON to deliver the content to the mobile app.

Now my problem is there is an option to publish the article at a certain date, so I want to validate the date to check it is valid.

So to test possibilites I made a small script. I am using `strtotime()` to check the date is valid, my script is:

```
<?php

    $date[] = '2011-31-01';
    $date[] = '2011-02-31';

    foreach($date as $str) {
        if(strtotime($str) == false) {
            $result[] = '<p>[' . $str . '] Resulted in an <span style="color: red;">Error.</span></p>';
        } else {
            $result[] = '<p>[' . $str . '] Resulted in <span style="color: green;">Success.</span></p>';
        }
    }

    foreach($result as $return) {
        echo $return;
    }

?>
```

Now my problem is the date `2011-02-31` which is `31st February 2011` is returning as valid, when obviously it isn't. So my question is why does it do this? and is there a better method to check that the date is valid and exists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [strtotime() converts a non existing date to another date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583579/strtotime-converts-a-non-existing-date-to-another-date)

Comment: `2011-01-31` gets parsed to `31. January 2011` (which would be correct) for me… Apart from that, `strtotime` is not meant to validate dates, but to try to parse dates in the best possible way (regardless of their format).

Comment: @hakre It's not a duplicate as my problem has nothing to do with the date being converted to something else. Thanks anyway.

Comment: WTF? How is 2011-01-31, 31st **February** 2011??

Comment: @AlixAxel sorry I wrote it our wrong it should of been `2011-02-31`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`checkdate();`](http://php.net/checkdate)  Validates a Gregorian date. Returns TRUE if the date given is valid; otherwise returns FALSE.

```
 if(checkdate(2, 31, 2011)){
      echo "Yeah";

  } else {echo "nah";}
```

It returns false!

That's the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have one (or a small set) fixed format for your date string it will be hard to get an acceptable result. In case you know the format, you can either parse the string directly yourself (and test it afterwards with `checkdate`), or you use [`strptime`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) to try parsing against known formats until you get a valid result.

If you don’t know the format, and you have to use `strtotime`, then you are required to accept that `strtotime` will try parsing the date string in the best possible way. This may lead to different dates than it was expected to be.